# jQuery .on() event cannot grab data from Ajax loaded content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic

Hey folks I have content being displayed on a page by using jQuery and Ajax to query my php page. On click I check for all elements with the class edit. I am trying to then grab the unique id of the link that was chosen. I know it should be this.id but it returns nothing. Does anyone have any insight on how to dynamically check the clicked link and get a stored value in any way?

The bellow works for getting a link clicked. but cannot get the id still.

```
$("body").on("click", ".edit", function(){
    var id = this.id;
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Here is the HTML that is being put on the page via Ajax

```
<div class="row">
             <div class="small-2 large-2 columns">3</div>
             <div class="small-10 large-6 columns">Andrew</div>
             <div class="small-6 large-2 columns">2013-08-12</div>
             <div class="small-6 large-2 columns edit"><a href="#" id="e3"> Edit </a></div>
        </div>
```

Solved solution was to use '.edit > a' as the selector. I had edit as the class of the div, not the anchor tag. Thanks for all the help folks!

Comment: Can you show more ? It's hard to spot your problem there.

Comment: how is `$(this).val()` related to the `id` var? anchor tags don't have a value...

Comment: I think he get data from site runned by Ajax (probably .done(html) ) and then he put html to "body.

Comment: What is the element tag that contains the `.edit` class? We really need a sample of the HTML markup to be able to help.

Comment: +1 once you added the HTML (was about to be -1 before you added that) :) Suggest you use JSFiddle in future to show problems. Much easier to demonstrate and fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample HTML helped:

You need to select the anchor within the .edit div.

```
$("body").on("click", ".edit > a", function () {
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
});
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QckbT/

Comment: Thank you SirI did not see that and I did not know you could select like that. After 5 hours of soul searching and tears you saved the day. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

Does this works ?

```
$("a.edit").on("click", function(){
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(this).val());
```

relate to body, not to #id.